# removing continuation lines from an indicator zone in pine script 5?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

im trying to remove the messy lines out of my script (image attached) I want the indicator to show only during session time 0930-1600.

[image of issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y2VEJ.png)

```
indicator('ORB MG 5', overlay=true, timeframe="5")
inputMax = input(5, title='ORB total time (minutes)')
sess = input.session('0930-0935', title='Session Time')
t = time(timeframe.period, sess + ':23456')
hide = timeframe.isintraday and timeframe.multiplier <= inputMax
is_newbar(res) =>
    ta.change(time(res)) != 0
in_session = not na(t)
is_first = in_session and not in_session[1]
orb_high = float(na)
orb_low = float(na)
if is_first
    orb_high := high
    orb_low := low
    orb_low
else
    orb_high := orb_high[1]
    orb_low := orb_low[1]
    orb_low
if high > orb_high and in_session
    orb_high := high
    orb_high
if low < orb_low and in_session
    orb_low := low
    orb_low
    

//Plot
line1 = orb_high
line2 = orb_low
p1PlotID = plot(line1, title='ORB High', color = color.red, linewidth = 2)
p2PlotID = plot(line2, title='ORB High', color = color.red, linewidth = 2)
fill(p1PlotID, p2PlotID, line1 > line2 ? color.new(color.red, 75) : color.new(color.red, 75))
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please refer to the image in the link to see the actual problem